# Questions about J-holomorphic curves as minimal surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I am a beginner in symplectic geometry. The questions I ask may be so trivial.

In McDuff's *"What is Symplectic Geometry?"*, she writes:

> We saw earlier that the symplectic area of a surface is
> invariant under deformations of the surface that fix its boundary. (Cf. Figure 1.3 (I).)
> It follows easily that their metric area can *only increase* under such deformations, i.e.
> J-holomorphic curves are so-called $g_J$-minimal surfaces.

What I don't understand is why the symplectic area is invariant under the deformation of with boundary it follows that the metric area can only increase under this deformation.

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: This is because by definition, a symplectic form $\omega$ is closed so when you integrate the form, you apply Stokes and you are left with an integral that depends on the boundary.

Comment: @AlvinJin Thanks for your comment. I know $omega$ is closed induces that symplectic area only depends on the boundary. But I don't why this fact can explain  metric area can only increase under such deformations, where $g_J(w,v)=\omega (w,Jv)$.

Comment: The [Wirtinger inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050793/proof-of-the-wirtinger-inequality/2051431#2051431) is the missing important fact. I suspect it's in McDuff's discussion.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks!